# CouchRest Model: Using multiple database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchrest

Is it possible to use multiple couchdb databases for data in rails app while using the [CouchRest Model gem](https://github.com/couchrest/couchrest_model)? Right now in my rails app I specify the one couchDB database in `config/couchdb.yml`. I was wondering if it possible to have more than one couchdb databases being used by one rails app?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this answer - it worked for my case where I wanted a database for each user

[Recommended use of couchrest model in a multi-tenant app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25369695/recommended-use-of-couchrest-model-in-a-multi-tenant-app)